# How to maintain alignment of an absolute item inside a changing flex-parent?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, absolute

Basically, I have a few banners overtop of some images inside a flex-box. The images are aligned according to the CSS while the flexbox is in its *flex-direction: row* orientation, then they all bunch at the top and smother each other when the flex box switches to *flex-direction: column*.

```
<html>
    <div class="locations">
        <div class="location">
            <img src="resources/images/norbert-toth-I1oL89qxefc-unsplash.jpg" />
            <div class="location-container>
                <h2>Herring Bone Library</h2>
                <p>141 Address St. <br>Detroit, MI <br>49449</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="location ">
            <img src="resources/images/kristen-colada-adams-wpCJlKxCNRA-unsplash.jpg" />
            <div class="location-container">
                <h2>Sunrise Botanical <br>(Downstairs)</h2>
                <p>2397 Hatchet Rd. <br>Suite 11 <br>Detroit, MI <br>49447</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="location">
            <img src="resources/images/daria-volkova-_IhXaHmTJr8-unsplash.jpg" />
            <div class="location-container">
                <h2>Black Cat Coffee</h2>
                <p>686 My Mind <br>Detroit, MI <br> 49448</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</html>
```

Essentially with the added CSS, the banners with the class *location-container* don't change their orientation with the flex-box, and they display on top of one another only in the first parent.

Here's their CSS:

```
.locations {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 3rem 4rem;
    gap: 2rem;
    position: relative;
}

.location-container {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #fffaf7;
    margin-left: 1rem;
    padding: 1rem;
    top: 1rem;
}

.location-container h2 {
    font-family: "Roboto Condensed", sans-serif;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
} 

.location-container p {
    font-family: "Cabin", sans-serif;
}

.location img {
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 46rem;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
    .locations {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        flex-direction: column;
        margin: 3rem 4rem;
        gap: 2rem;
        position: relative;
    }

    .location-container {
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #fffaf7;
        margin-left: 1rem;
        padding: 1rem;
        top: 1rem;
    }
}
```

It's expected that once the width of the webpage reaches 1200px, the flex-box will change orientation to direction: column, and the text containers will stay in their relative places.

Is there any way to keep the banners in their proper locations when the parent containers flex?

Answer (score 0):

In your media `1200px` you are still using `position:absolute`. You need to set it `location-container` class to `relative` once you are in that viewport. Also you need to add `min-width` to it so that each `location-container` is equal.

```css
.locations {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 3rem 4rem;
    gap: 2rem;
    position: relative;
}

.location-container {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #fffaf7;
    margin-left: 1rem;
    padding: 1rem;
    top: 1rem;
}

.location-container h2 {
    font-family: "Roboto Condensed", sans-serif;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
} 

.location-container p {
    font-family: "Cabin", sans-serif;
}

.location img {
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 46rem;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
    .locations {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        flex-direction: column;
        margin: 3rem 4rem;
        gap: 2rem;
        position: relative;
    }

    .location-container {
        position: relative;
        background-color: #fffaf7;
        margin-left: 1rem;
        padding: 1rem;
        top: 1rem;
        min-width:300px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="locations">
    <div class="location">
        <div class="location-container">
            <h2>Herring Bone Library</h2>
            <p>141 Address St. <br>Detroit, MI <br>49449</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="location">
        <div class="location-container">
            <h2>Sunrise Botanical <br>(Downstairs)</h2>
            <p>2397 Hatchet Rd. <br>Suite 11 <br>Detroit, MI <br>49447</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="location">
        <div class="location-container">
            <h2>Black Cat Coffee</h2>
            <p>686 My Mind <br>Detroit, MI <br> 49448</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It may not be true for your original code, but the first `<div class="location-container>` is missing a closing `"` in the class attribute. That will get in the way and need to be corrected (done in the snippet).

You made the `absolute` positioned `location-container` relative to `.locations` with ending `s`, but they should be relative to `.location` without the `s`.

So

- remove `position: relative` from `.locations`
- add `.location { position: relative }` to your CSS

And you're good to go.

BTW, I did noting about overflowing `.location` content, but added some nice random pictures to show the effect.

**UPDATE** after looking deeper into your code I noticed that all but  *flexbox* `.locations { flex-direction: column }` is different. There is no need to define the other properties a second time.

Rule of thumb:

- define all properties outside a media query that stay the same for each device.
- inside a media query override only the properties that need to be changed and/or add new ones. In this case, only `flex-direction` needs to be changed.

I adjusted the snippet accordingly...

```css
.locations {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 3rem 4rem;
    gap: 2rem;

/*    position: relative; /* REMOVE */
}

/* ADD */
.location {
    position: relative;
}

.location-container {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #fffaf7;
    margin-left: 1rem;
    padding: 1rem;
    top: 1rem;
}

.location-container h2 {
    font-family: "Roboto Condensed", sans-serif;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.location-container p {
    font-family: "Cabin", sans-serif;
}

.location img {
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 46rem;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
    .locations {
        flex-direction: column;
   }
}
```

```html
<div class="locations">

    <div class="location">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/700?random=1">
        <div class="location-container">
            <h2>Herring Bone Library</h2>
            <p>141 Address St. <br>Detroit, MI <br>49449</p>
        </div>
   </div>

    <div class="location">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/700?random=2">
        <div class="location-container">
            <h2>Sunrise Botanical <br>(Downstairs)</h2>
            <p>2397 Hatchet Rd. <br>Suite 11 <br>Detroit, MI <br>49447</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="location">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/700?random=3">
        <div class="location-container">
            <h2>Black Cat Coffee</h2>
            <p>686 My Mind <br>Detroit, MI <br> 49448</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```